# Simple SQLite ORM in C#, code works but how to solve race condition

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, orm

To practice C# programming, I created this simple SQLite query writer + ORM using [`Microsoft.Data.SQLite`](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite) and I wrote few unit tests (using [`xunit`](https://github.com/xunit/xunit)) to make sure code is working. The problem is when I run each unit test individually it all works but if I all test at once, the code fails and says the database is locked or code goes into infinite loop.

I am wondering if there a way to make the code threadsafe using `lock(variable) {}`, I am not sure. Maybe there is something wrong with the way I handle transactions (I used transactions only for `INSERT` statements).

This is the function that I think is problematic. Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper function that creats SQL commands
/// </summary>
/// <param name="commandText"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private void CreateAndExecuteNonQueryCommand(string commandText)
{
    if (SqliteConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        SqliteConnection.Open();
    }

    var transaction = SqliteConnection.BeginTransaction();
    var command = SqliteConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    Transactions.Add(transaction);

    try
    {             
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(e?.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        transaction.Commit();
        transaction.Dispose();
        command.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The code is a little long so [this the link](https://github.com/amir734jj/Sqlite-ORM/tree/8f08e8ed6c19258c6b150b9ed91802fb8751f838) to the last commit as I write this question.

Comment: Where do you close the `SqliteConnection`?

Comment: I agree, this might not actually be a race condition, but a resource not being cleaned up properly between each unit test. Unit tests are generally not run in parallel unless explicitly told to do so, as it can cause unintended and hard-to-reproduce side effects

Comment: What's the point of doing transaction commit in finally? You don't care if exception happened and want to try to commit anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqliteStorage.cs contains method `public T RetrieveModel(Dictionary<string, object> keyValueDictionary)`. There you use `CreateCommand` method then call `ExecuteReader();` but this reader is not closed. Just add this string `reader.Dispose();` in the bottom of `RetrieveModel`. To avoid this situation you can use `using` block. It calls `Dispose` automatically.